Should we participate in Winter Bash 2013?
Below is the 2013 announcement. Should we participate? Vote below.
As another year draws to a close, we wanted to do something fun and lighthearted with our communities, as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make the sites awesome. So, we’re announcing Winter Bash 2013!
Most of you probably remember last year’s event, but I’ll recap anyway, for the newbies among us. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard that looks something like this: 

Winter Bash 2013 will again be available to all sites that choose to participate. We’re redesigning the landing page and redesigning all the hats to keep things fresh and exciting. 
Some Details
This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

When do "we" have to decide by?

The email says we have to submit our answer by 1 December.

After participating in the Winter Bash on SO last year, I'd say we should. Yes, it's kind of silly, but it does motivate users to contribute. And, honestly, after getting into the spirit of it on SO (and other participating SE network sites, which I believe is/was most of them), I found it kind of disappointing that I wasn't getting any hats for my contributions on crypto.SE.

@IlmariKaronen I was also disappointed that the vote came out against last year.

@mikeazo Looks like the "yays" will have it this year :)

Yes we should participate in Winter Bash 2013!

Adding hats sounds like fun; It might persuade [more] people to get [more] involved

The network lives on gamification… adding a bit more fun won't hurt anyone (from my point of view).

No we should not (remember that individual users will have the option to opt out and not see the hats, etc).

They provide an ulterior motive that could lead to substandard actions as people aim for hit hat-based-targets.

@user8911 So do badges and rep points but it seems to be working reasonably well...

@rath: Agreed, was just trying to work out if there were any significant reasons for/against it at the time. Unfortunately I didn't realize that votes still got locked-in even on meta (hence the only negative vote!)
